# Bit shift operations by values greater than size of data type

Tags: c#, roslyn, bit-shift

I was looking at some C# IL disassembly, and I noticed the C# compiler adds a `&` operation to ensure the right side of a shift operation is always less than the size of the word in bits. For example,

`int word = 1 << x`

compiles to

`int word = 1 << (x & 0x1F)`

and

`long word = 1L << x`

compiles to

`long word = 1L << (x & 0x3F)`

I've always assumed that 32-bit shift operations by greater than 31 and 64-bit shift operations by greater than 63 would just result in zero, is my assumption incorrect? Can there be undefined behavior when shifting by more than the size of the data type? If not, why does the C# compiler do this?